# Sub set of list using Java Script

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to create a sub set of the list from a given list.

For example, I have a list of fields which can be checked and unchecked. I am trying to create a sub list which will only have those items which are checked.

I am unable to create it using Javascript as I am very new to the language.

```js
this.attributeCategoryOptions.forEach((el) => {
    el.description += ' Required';
});

if (this.args.formData.descriptionDefaultFieldId) {
    this.descriptionDefaultFieldSelected = this.descriptionDefaultFieldOptions.find(
        (el) => this.args.formData.descriptionDefaultFieldId === el.id
    );
}

if (this.args.formData.iconUrl) {
    this.iconUrlSelected = this.iconUrlOptions.find(
        (el) => this.args.formData.iconUrl === el.id
    );
}


if (this.args.formData.attributeDescriptionIdOptions != null) {
    this.attributeCategoryOptions.forEach((listItem) => {
        listItem.checked = false;

        this.args.formData.attributeDescriptionIdOptions.forEach((attr) => {
            if (listItem.id === attr.id) {
                listItem.checked = attr.checked;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: what is `formData`?

Comment: also welcome! I don't have enough information to fully answer your question, but since you're working with checked state, and I see the *word* formData, it reminds me of this code I wrote very recently -- https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/baobab-ram/blob/main/ui/app/components/settings.gts#L75-L98

Checkboxes (when represented in FormData) don't report their unchecked state, so you'd need to query that manually

Comment: for reference: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=mdn+FormData